# C# TCP/ IP communication sending delayed acknowledgement

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, network-programming, wireshark

I am working with a client server model. My client is `192.168.77.6` and my server is `192.168.77.18`. I am sending a request to the server, and I am able to receive data from the server. Now, as soon as I receive the last data packet response (`[PSH,ACK]` line 428 in wireshark packet) to my request, C# is sending a `[ACK]` of 0 bytes which causes the server to send a `[FIN,ACK]` packet and causes it to terminate the connection. I want to delay this last `[ACK]` packet, because I require to an acknowledgement of 2 bytes to the server (line 479 of wireshark packet). Since the server terminates the connection, it does not accept this 2 bytes of acknowledgement that I am sending. I am not sure what the issue is here.

[Wireshark Packet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7p8yH.png)

I have included my code below:

```cs
TcpClient tcpclnt;
NetworkStream stream;
tcpclnt = new TcpClient();
tcpclnt.Connect(ip, port);
stream = tcpclnt.GetStream();
if (tcpclnt.Connected)
{
    SendMessage(stream, RequestToSend);
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    string readData = "";
    readData = readBytes1(stream);                
}
tcpclnt.Close();
```

Below is the `readBytes1()` function:

```
private static string readBytes1(NetworkStream stream)
        {
            byte[] resp = new byte[100];
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            int bytes;
            do
            {
                bytes = 0;
                bytes = stream.Read(resp, 0, resp.Length);
                memoryStream.Write(resp, 0, bytes);                
            }
            while (bytes > 0);

            GenerateAcknowledgement(stream);
            

            return Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());

        }
```

`GenerateAcknowledgement()` is the function that sends 2 bytes of data that is not being processed by the server because of the earlier acknowledgement of 0 bytes which caused the server to send a FIN packet and terminate the connection.

Comment: What is your server program really doing after it replied to the request? Are you sure the server *program* doesn't just close the connection?

Comment: Yes, after the server replies to the request, it closes the connection, after the client sends an ack packet acknowledging that it has read the response from the server. I want to delay this response that the client program is sending, to prevent the server from closing the connection

Comment: That's not really how TCP works.Delaying an ACK will just make the other end enter a retry loop for a while until it gives up with an error on the connection. And the server program have still closed its end of the connection so it can't be reused anyway.

Comment: What is the protocol you use on top of TCP? If it's HTTP why not use the `Connection` header to keep the connection alive? Or if it's some other protocol, then you have to check its documentation to see if it's possible to keep the connection open.

Comment: And (which I should have asked earlier) what is the actual problem you need to solve by "delaying" the `ACK` packet? Please [edit] your question to include that piece of important information. Without it, your question is really an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Comment: I have edited my question. I am using TCP client server request response model to send a request and to receive a response.

Comment: You have zero control of the ACK packets at the application layer.  This is the responsibility of the TCP Stack.  I can't see the trace above due to firewall issues on my side.  But chances are high that everything at the link level is working perfectly.  Perhaps a reinvestigation into the application is in order.  TCP will enter a retry state if there's no proper responses, it will then time out after 10 tries.

Comment: TCP is an transport layer protocol, it doesn't have "request-response" semantics. Whatever "requests" and "responses" you send and receives are part of an application layer protocol. Which application level protocol are you using? A common one like HTTP, or your own protocol?

Comment: I am using my own protocol. Not a common one.

Comment: I have added my code to the post